# With GitLab CI/CD, how to have code cloned in a container by user:group 'java:java', instead of 'root?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux, cicd

In a GitLab repo, I have a **Dockerfile** with the following lines,

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN addgroup -S java
RUN adduser -s /bin/bash -S -G java java
USER java
WORKDIR /home/java
```

so that when the image is instantiated (container running), it will run as user ‘**java**’

When GitLab CI/CD clones the project code however, it is owned by root in directory `/home/java`

This is unexpected behavior, I would expect it to be owned by user ‘**java**’

How do I get the code to be cloned by user ‘java’, and owned (**user:group**), by **user:group** ‘**java:java**’?

Comment: Can you update your post with your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Please redact any sensitive information you wouldn't want on the Internet. Seeing how you run the pipeline will help get an answer.

Comment: Having the code owned by root is usually good practice; it prevents the application from accidentally overwriting itself.  I don't see the `COPY` line in the Dockerfile that would copy the application code into the image, though; is this missing?

Comment: Posting my .gitlab-ci.yml is irrelevant, find and use any .gitlab-ci.yml you can find, that one will work to demonstrate this case.

Comment: Ummm no, it is not (it is false to say that "having the code owned by root is usually a good practice"), that is misinformation and completely wrong.  It is not a good practice to have root own the code.  In fact it is not a good practice to even have root as a user in the container.  The best practice is to have rootless containers.  Please stop spreading this misinformation.

Comment: Additionally, there is no COPY line in the Docker file that would copy the application code into the image, that is not missing (it is not an error that it is not there).  With GitLab CI/CD, the code of the corresponding repo is automatically cloned into the image.  This is how GitLab CI/CD works - the issue is that GitLab CI/CD clones the code as root, when the USER is set to 'java'.

Answer (score 2):

GitLab CI clones the code outside your job container using the `gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper` docker image ([repository for runner helper](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/container_registry/1472754)). If you're running your own executor you can override what helper image is used for cloning the repository to one that clones using a java user though you'd have to make sure that the user/group ID matched in the two containers to prevent issues. This would also mean you're maintaining your own extended runner helper and you couldn't use the shared runners hosted by GitLab.

You have an alternate possible approach though I wouldn't recommend it: You could set your git strategy to not clone your repo, then clone it in a `before_script:` action within your job container, which would cause it to clone with your java user. However this will only clone the repository within that one job, so you'd have to repeat yourself across every job which would violate DRY all over the place.

Generally though, I'd agree with David that having the code owned by root is fine in this case unless you have a specific reason to change

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not even close however to getting this to work with the information given.

Comment: @user10664542 - Can you specify which approach you'd like to pursue? It sounds like you'd like to either clone the helper image or clone in `before_script`, since if you were OK with the code being owned by root there isn't much to get working. Once you've specified which approach you'd like, I can provide some further info.

Answer (score 1):

Projects in GitLab are cloned with the GitLab runner helper image, which is using `root`. It will also use `umask 0000` to avoid permission issues, if data is cached.

See [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1736) for more details.

To fix your issue, add an environment variable:
`FF_DISABLE_UMASK_FOR_DOCKER_EXECUTOR=true`

This will disable the umask usage and the runner tries to get UID and GID from the image of the build container.